# Cannot set variable value in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to change the value of `shell-command-default-error-buffer` variable in emacs.

First i view the variable to see its present value -

```
C-h v RET
shell-command-default-error-buffer
```

The output is -

```
shell-command-default-error-buffer is a variable defined in `simple.el'.
Its value is nil
```

Then I try to set the value -

```
M-x set-variable RET
shell-command-default-error-buffer
```

It shows me error - `[No match]`

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
M-: (setq shell-command-default-error-buffer THE-VALUE-YOU-WANT)
```

If the variable were a user option, then you could also do this, instead:

```
M-x set-variable RET shell-command-default-error-buffer RET THE-VALUE-YOU-WANT
```

You had a space between `set` and `variable` in what you tried.  But that just had the effect of completing `set` to `set-`, and when you typed `variable` you got the same thing as the second above.

The problem was that `shell-command-default-error-buffer` is not a user option, so command `set-variable` does not recognize it as a variable that it can set.

Comment: I don't know the concept of `user options` I'll need to read the docs. But the manual [here](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/shell.html) says that `If you set the variable shell-command-default-error-buffer to shell-command-default-error-buffer error output is inserted in the buffer of that name.` So how does the manual instruct to set this variable if that is not possible?

Comment: Kshitiz Sharma: You *can* set it; just not with `M-x set-variable`. Either use `M-: (setq ...)` as Drew pointed out, or add the `(setq ...)` form to your .emacs file to make the change persistent.

Comment: Arguably this *should* be a user option, though. You could `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request the change.

Comment: @phils Okay. `M-:` gives me `Wrong type argument, wholenump, -1`. How do I type in the lisp expression?

Comment: Typing `M-:` (i.e. meta colon) should give you an "Eval:" prompt at which you can enter the expression. Alternatively, use `M-x eval-expression` (which the command that `M-:` is normally bound to).

Comment: Try `C-h k M-:`, to see what command `M-:` is bound to.  Normally, it is bound to command `eval-expression`.  If it is not, you can use `M-x eval-expression RET` to invoke the command.

Comment: User options have an asterisk as the first character of their documentation string. In a way, it's similar to how functions with an `interactive` form are commands which can be invoked with `M-x`, while other functions cannot. See e.g. http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_143.html

Comment: As the link points out, variables declared with `defcustom` don't need the asterisk, so the proper answer (save for the superfluous, needless redundancy :-) is that user options are marked as user options.